# Angular: Reactive form validation with pattern is not working as expected

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am using angular 5 and reactive forms and I am trying to validate the email by using the below regex

```
^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$
```

I have tested this regex in https://regexr.com/

[image]

The same regex when used in angular reactive form -> validators.compose
[image]

[image]

it fails.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with how I have used the email regex, we should not enclose regex in '' but should be enclosed in //

emailPattern

```
/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
```

For some reason I my project regex was enclosed in '' and was working fine.

Here is sandbox link if anybody wants to look deep into this
https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-monad-7p2y3?file=/src/app/app.component.ts